# Property 'PrintingSystem' is 'ReadOnly' Error (Occurred after upgrading to DevExpress 11.1.8)

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I just upgrade to DevExpress 11.1.8 and I am now getting the following error:

**Property 'PrintingSystem' is 'ReadOnly' error.**

This used to work under DevExpress 9.1.4

How should I refactor this code to work under 11.1.8?

```
Dim DateTerminationFrom As DateTime = "12/1/2010"
Dim DateTerminationThru As DateTime = "12/31/2010"
Dim report As New rptStudentCertificationExpirationNoticePostCardAddress(DateTerminationFrom, DateTerminationThru)
report.PrintingSystem = ctlStudentCodeUpdateBadgePreview.PrintingSystem
report.CreateDocument()
```

In VS 2010, the 'report.PrintingSystem' is flagged as the error.

Comment: Take a look at this [ticket](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/B147642.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching the line below around and using the PrintControl1 method fixed the issue:

```
ctlStudentCodeUpdateBadgePreview.PrintControl1.PrintingSystem = report.PrintingSystem
```

This makes sense too. The ctlStudentCodeUpdateBadgePreview is a PrintSystem control dropped on the page. The report is a DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport that is its own control and should be read-only.